# Why TouchDown, TouchUp events don't appear in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone

I'm developping a Windows Phone 7.1 application. I make the design with Expression Blend 4 and then, I program the code in WPF.

I have some Path objects and I want to detect the TouchDown and TouchUp events of those objects, but my problem is that those events don't appear! :O

I only have Tap and Hold events, but not TouchDown and TouchUp (in general, events that use TouchEventArgs class).

Do I need some external library?
As I can see in MSDN, TouchEventArgs class exists from version 4.0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.toucheventargs(v=vs.100).aspx).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're developing a Windows Phone 7.1 app, you're doing it with [**Silverlight for Windows Phone**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426934%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). That is not WPF.

The [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590078%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class in Silverlight does not have `TouchDown` or `TouchUp` events, as [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590078.aspx) in WPF has.

You may use [Manipulation Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. 
But then, how can I know when the user is tapping and when the user release the finger?
I need to change the Fill property of a control while the user is tapping the screen and restore it when release.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you look into [Manipluation Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933(v=vs.95).aspx)?